# SQL query in QueryBuilder

Tags: laravel

My query works fine in phpMyadmin, but I can't convert this sql query to querybuilder . i have problems with "distinct" any help please ?

```
SELECT sum(`users`.`ca`), sum(distinct `sales`.`amount`), `users`.`id` , `users`.`email` 
FROM `sales`,`users` 
WHERE `sales`.`user_id`=`users`.`id` 
GROUP BY `user_id`
```

In my querybuilder

```
$results = DB::table('users')
    ->select('users.id', 'users.email', DB::raw('SUM(users.ca)'), DB::raw('SUM(sales.amount)'))
    ->join('sales', 'users.id', '=', 'sales.user_id')
    ->groupBy('users.id')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Can you please share the error you are getting here
and try to debug it with using *toSql()* to get query running behind the scene of the query builder https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_toSql

Comment: The result are working fine but [sum(distinct `sales`.`amount`)] is not the exact result. I would like to know how to convert this part into laravel querybuilder

Comment: It doesn't look like you're using `distinct` in your Laravel query.